# Iterating through tags in Python

Tags: python, django, printing, meta

I am iterating through meta tags in Python with the aim of printing them to the console.

```
for i in soup.head:
print(soup.meta)
```

The problem I'm having is that the code is printing the very first meta tag it reads for every instance of tag that it finds. How can I increment the soup.meta to print the next tag?

Comment: You're printing the same thing on each iteration - you aren't progressing at all.  (`print(soup.meta)` is always the same value as it isn't being changed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're iterating over a collection, but for every element you print something unrelated -`soup.meta`. Try something like this:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('meta'):
    do_something(tag)
```